# Correct codes format to set the chart coordinates, title, font and added text in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Wrote a macro to draw line with markers plot with excel, it works well in a single macro xlsm file. But when I tried to convert it to a excel addin (xlam file) , it got a lot of bugs.  All the bugs are related to the format of both X and Y coordinates, position, font type and size of chart title, and position, font type and sizeof added text.  Not sure what is the reason, need to know the correct format of them.  Any debug suggestions or help, really appreciated.  Please see my full macro codes as the following. Thanks.
The error message is[image][image]
But you checked with excel, the plot was drawn without chart title and the add text (that I want) and the format of coordinate was not that I tried to set. Again all these errors only happen with the xlam file, the macro works well with xlms fie.

```
Sub data_plot()


sh_rows = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B65535").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To sh_rows

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value < 0.000001 Then

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1000000000# * ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

    End If
Next i


ii = sh_rows


c_name = "chart1"

On Error GoTo err:
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(c_name).Delete
err:
Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(330, 120, 480, 270)  'set graph position and size
ch.Name = c_name


With ch.Chart

    For iii = 1 To 2

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(iii).Values = _
              Range(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, iii + 1), 
              ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ii, iii + 1))
        .SeriesCollection(iii).XValues = _
              Range(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), 
              ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ii, 1))


        .SeriesCollection(iii).ChartType = xlLineMarkers


    Next iii

    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "[110]"
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = 2
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 12
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)



    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "[001]"
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerStyle = 2
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerSize = 12
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(96, 96, 96)
    .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(96, 96, 96)
    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(96, 96, 96)


    With .Legend
        .IncludeInLayout = False
        .Position = xlLegendPositionRight
        .AutoScaleFont = False
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Top = 25
        .Left = 392
        .Width = 72
        .Height = 40
    End With

    With .ChartArea.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 33
       '.Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With


    With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'red
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(96, 96, 96) 'grey
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    .HasTitle = True

    With .ChartTitle
        .Text = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 8)
        .Left = 358
        .Top = 236

        With .Font
            .Name = "Tahoma"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With


    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Text = "Position(nm)"  'X-axis title
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10 'X-axis coordinate number size
        .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'X-axis title word font size
        .TickMarkSpacing = 3
        .TickLabelSpacing = 5
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0._);[red](#,##0.)"
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##0_);[red](#,##0)"
        .TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "0_);[red](0.)"
    End With

    With .Axes(xlValue)

       .HasTitle = True
       .AxisTitle.Text = "Strain"   'Y-aixs title
       .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'y-axis title word font size
       'Minimum value of Y axis
       .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -0.005
       .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormatLocal = "0.0%"

    End With

End With



Dim thechartobj As ChartObject
Set thechartobj = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ch.Name)
Dim thechart As Chart    
Set thechart = thechartobj.Chart
Dim thetextbox As Shape
Set thetextbox = thechart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 688, 372, 122, 20)
With thetextbox.TextFrame.Characters
    .Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 8)
    With .Font
        .Name = "tahoma"
        .Size = 10
        .Bold = msoTrue
    End With
End With

Set ch.Name = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 8)

With ch.Chart
    .Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\\" & ch.Name & ".jpg"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I checked... there is a non closed With statement in the code attached, so some of the functions are not working. Check it.

Comment: The original one does not include

Comment: There are 12 "with" statements and 11 "end with" statements, so that code can not work without an error or unexpected result...

Comment: I counted few times, there  are 12 with and 12 "end with", I have no idea which "end with" you missed. Again, this macro works well with single xlsm file, only not working in the addin XLAM file, if there is one "End With" missed, it should not be working in the xlsm files as well. Could you help to count them again?